# Cannot read property of underfined

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am getting a weird error. I'm using Angular and Firebase *(Real time DB)* in a project and even thou everything is rendering correctly, I'm getting errors on the log.

> VM368 OpenIdeasComponent.ngfactory.js:20 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'firstName' of undefined
>           at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (VM368 OpenIdeasComponent.ngfactory.js:36)
>           at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (VM346 vendor.js:57875)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (VM346 vendor.js:57250)
>           at callViewAction (VM346 vendor.js:57486)
>           at execEmbeddedViewsAction (VM346 vendor.js:57449)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (VM346 vendor.js:57246)
>           at callViewAction (VM346 vendor.js:57486)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (VM346 vendor.js:57428)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (VM346 vendor.js:57251)
>           at callViewAction (VM346 vendor.js:57486)

On the database, under the Features collection I have a reference for the author ID that belongs to another collection called **users**.

On my `FeaturesModel` constructor I have `author?: AuthorModel` to be as an optional parameter.

So, when I initiate my component, I use a `forEach` to fetch the **author data** from the **users collection** and assign that object to the feature object.

Here is the code:

### ideas.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.fService.getFullFeature().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.features = data;
            this.features.forEach( el => {
              this.fService.getAuthor(el.userID).subscribe(
                authorData => {
                  const a = {
                    id: authorData.id,
                    firstName: authorData.firstName,
                    lastName: authorData.lastName,
                    email: authorData.email
                  };
                  el.author = a;
                },
                (e) => { console.error(e); }
              );
            });
            console.log(this.features);
          }
        );
    }
```

### html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div style="padding: 100px 0">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="green header text-center">Feature Summary</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-space link-effect" *ngFor="let idea of features" [routerLink]="['display/' + idea.id]" href="#modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">
                    <div class="col-7">
                        <span class="open-ideas">{{ idea.title }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 d-xs-none">
                        {{ idea.author.firstName }} {{ idea.author.lastName }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 d-xs-none">
                        <fa name="thumbs-up"></fa>
                        {{ idea.votes }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, in theory, now I have a object that contains the author's information, on the HTML I'm adding `{{ feature.author.firstName }}`, which works BUT I'm getting this console error.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: can you add the Html snippet as well?

Comment: @TiagoSilva for sure! There ya go! Thanks

Comment: el.author has no correlation to idea.author that we can see. The error is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your subscriptions inside the forEach are not completed when `{{ feature.author.firstName }}` is rendered at the very begining. This is why you get the error but still see the variable display in HTML, because it is rendered after the subscription is complete, hence after the error message.

You should use `await async` in this case

```
async ngOnInit() {
    //created another promise
    const promise1 = await this.fService.getFullFeature().toPromise().then(
      async data => {
        this.features = data;
        this.features.forEach( el => {
          //you wait for the promise to complete in order for your code to move on
          //this might be slow if you have a lot of data in the this.features array
          const promise2 = await this.fService.getAuthor(el.userID).toPromise().then(
             authorData => {
              const a = {
                id: authorData.id,
                firstName: authorData.firstName,
                lastName: authorData.lastName,
                email: authorData.email
              };
              el.author = a;
            }
          ).catch((e) => { console.error(e); });
        });
        console.log(this.features);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey @Whitewolf3131 thank you! I tried that but still didn't work. I got the same error but this time it didn't load the entire list. Just the first element.

Comment: Hmm, I believe the guily one is the first subscription then. Let me modify the code for you and try again.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I don't have any other ideas. Debugging might be the best.